how to extract exact scanimage command from "document scanner" tool
I want to automate my scans that I used to perform with the "document scanner" GUI tool.
I am aware of scanimage command (that is most likely used internally), that can be used as such
scanimage -d "epson2:libusb:002:003" --format=tiff | convert tiff:- scan.jpg

There are some settings that are obvious needed to reproduce my GUI scans (e.g. --resolution 2400 --method color) but I found that the image dimensions are still different when using the CLI command.
Therefore I was wondering if there is a way to see which command the GUI tool uses internally. There might be a bunch of flags that I am not even aware of, so this is interesting to see!

The script command.  script -c [gui command here] ~/script.log.  Use it, as usual.  Then read the log file.

super cool, will try when back at scanner!

unfortunately the script remains empty

I'm sorry, I'm checking the docs, and I had long forgotten exit.  It may not have mattered, but you're supposed to type exit when finished.  It may still be blank.  Some GUI's don't like script.  There's also scriptreplay ~/script.log, but I've never used it.  Just reading the log is faster.
